# Failed to find style vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I wanted to have viewpageindicator in my project, but am having trouble importing it. I've got errors in my XML.

```
Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.

Failed to find style 'vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle' in current theme
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="248dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/pager"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:padding="3dip" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

My updated res/values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="hololightnoactionbar" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="dividerstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/list_divider</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1px</item>
    </style>

    <style name="roundedwhitebox">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/roundedwhitebox</item>
    </style>

    <style name="roundedlightgraybox">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/roundedlightgraybox</item>
    </style>

    <style name="rotatingProgressCircle">
        <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/circleindeterminate</item>
    </style>

    <style name="StyledIndicators" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomCirclePageIndicator</item>
        <item name="vpiLinePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomLinePageIndicator</item>
        <item name="vpiTitlePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTitlePageIndicator</item>
        <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator</item>
        <item name="vpiUnderlinePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomUnderlinePageIndicator</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTitlePageIndicator">
        <item name="android:background">#18FF0000</item>
        <item name="footerColor">#FFAA2222</item>
        <item name="footerLineHeight">1dp</item>
        <item name="footerIndicatorHeight">3dp</item>
        <item name="footerIndicatorStyle">underline</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#AA000000</item>
        <item name="selectedColor">#FF000000</item>
        <item name="selectedBold">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomLinePageIndicator">
        <item name="strokeWidth">4dp</item>
        <item name="lineWidth">30dp</item>
        <item name="unselectedColor">#FF888888</item>
        <item name="selectedColor">#FF880000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomCirclePageIndicator">
        <item name="fillColor">#FF888888</item>
        <item name="strokeColor">#FF000000</item>
        <item name="strokeWidth">2dp</item>
        <item name="radius">10dp</item>
        <item name="centered">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTabPageIndicator" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator.Text</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF555555</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_divider</item>
        <item name="android:dividerPadding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:fadingEdge">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:fadingEdgeLength">8dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTabPageIndicator.Text" parent="android:TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomUnderlinePageIndicator">
        <item name="selectedColor">#FFCC0000</item>
        <item name="android:background">#FFCCCCCC</item>
        <item name="fadeLength">1000</item>
        <item name="fadeDelay">1000</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

My project structure is here, where vpilibrary is the imported viewpageindicator library

[image]

What's wrong with it? and let me know if you need more files for debugging. Thx

ps:My minsdkversion and targetsdkversion is both 16

Answer (score 16):

**Problem:**
[image: Problem]

**Solution:**

1. Add a custom style in `res/layout/values/styles.xml`

You can find some examples [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/res/values/styles.xml).

```
<style name="StyledIndicators" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomCirclePageIndicator</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomCirclePageIndicator">
    <item name="fillColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">1dp</item>
    <item name="radius">6dp</item>
    <item name="centered">true</item>
</style>
```

2. Add new style as a theme in your activity, "StyledIndicators":

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".YourActivity"
       android:theme="@style/StyledIndicators" >
   </activity>
   ```
3. After that just need to change to theme to the one that comes with the project, choose Manifest Themes - StyledIndicators.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomCirclePageIndicator</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomCirclePageIndicator">
    <item name="fillColor">#FF888888</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">#FF000000</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">2dp</item>
    <item name="radius">10dp</item>
    <item name="centered">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Now in your Manifest File.
Add theme attribute under

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="ViewPagerIndicator Sample"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Dont forget to add

```
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Answer (score 6):

The activity using ViewPagerIndicator needs to have the appropriate styles in its theme.

In [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/VPI), I demonstrate setting up a custom theme with the requisite `vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

        <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
                <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/TabStyle</item>
        </style>

        <style name="TabStyle" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator">
                <item name="android:textColor">#FF33AA33</item>
                <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
                <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
                <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
                <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
                <item name="android:fadingEdge">horizontal</item>
                <item name="android:fadingEdgeLength">8dp</item>
        </style>

</resources>
```

The same basic approach should work for `vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle`, and I would imagine that the sample code that accompanies ViewPagerIndicator has an example of this.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. thx. anyway I added ViewPAgerIndicator's sample style file into my style xml. but it still is missing. I guess I am still missing some component. please examine my updated style xml files for possible ignorance of it

Comment: @Daniel: Show in your manifest where your activity uses `StyledIndicators`.

Comment: I added the style like this to my styles.xml, and was stuck for hours until I realized I had multiple styles.xml files. Needed to add to all.

Answer (score 0):

To apply the custom style to the circle page indicator add the style attribute directly in your xml layout.

```
 <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        style="@style/CustomCirclePageIndicator"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```